# Vectorization of block consecutive matrixes in a Matrix (M = [N(1);N(2);...;N(n)])

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I want to vectorize the following code, but I do not know if this is possible (I added the code and an example set as links below). I have a [n,48] matrix with solutions called 'pop'. A solution 'x' is an 1x48 matrix containing indices to a matrix N. Each row in N defines a batch choice of products, where the columns 3:11 of N contain information about the amount of a product produced for a batch (column 3 = product 1, column 4 = product 2 etc), shown below:

```
N = [BatchID, na, Product 1, Product 2,..., Product 9,na,...;
           1, na,       100,         0,...,       220,na,...;
           2, na,         0,       340,...,         0,na,...;
           ...                                           
       30000, na,        80,         0,...,       120,na,...];
```

Therefore, the command N(x(:),3:11)' creates a 9x48 matrix where each column(n) corresponds with a batch choice and the rows with the amount of products produced by that choice, which would look like the following:

```
 Tt= [Batch index: 200,215,400,...,315;
      Product 1  :  0 , 50, 80,..., 40;
      Product 2  : 100,  0, 20,...,  0;
      ...
      Product 9  :  80, 20,  0,..., 20];
```

Every 6 columns corresponds to the production of one week and I need to know the total production of each week, where excessive products are added to the next week (the f1 and f2 define 9x1 vectors containing information about each product produced in that week in percentages). By combining all weeks (Nf = [f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8];) a matrix is created containing the production of products per week, which looks like:

```
Nf = [week nr. :   1,   2, ...,   8;
      Product 1:   1, 0.5, ..., 0.7;
      Product 2: 0.9,   1, ...,   1;
      ...
      Product 9: 0.8, 0.7, ..., 0.9];
```

This matrix is used to calculate a fitness in the following way:

```
V = exp(-Nf*5).*1000;    % Penalty for % product order not completed
```

f = sum(sum(V));   % Nf translated to a fitness value

Using these steps, for every x in pop a fitness f is calculated, however a for-loop is used to loop through pop, however this seems unnecessary.

With kind regards,

Paul

Ps. The solution of this attached files will be very bad, normally the string 'x' is 1x240, containing other batches that will introduce product types that are missing in 'pop.mat'

Link to example:
[file](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5250FEBC2C55AD6!172&authkey=!AMz864ARwK04KZw&ithint=folder%2cmat)